# How to upload file once in saucelabs and use it for other tests

Tags: java, android, appium, saucelabs

I am running a Mobile App test in Sauce labs Simulator.

I am uploading Android file (.apk) for every test ran on Saucelabs. It takes more time to run a single test.

My code

```
client = new SauceREST(authentication.getUsername(),
                authentication.getAccessKey());

sc.client.uploadFile(app, "QABeta", true);
```

testing.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">

    <test name="testing" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="apps.Test" />
            <class name="apps.Test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Command to run:-

1. Running single test

   mvn -Dtest=Test test -DFILEPATH=/PATH_TO_APK_FILE
2. Running multiple test

   mvn -Dtests=testing.xml test -DFILEPATH=/PATH_TO_APK_FILE

When I ran multiple tests, apk file will be uploaded for each test. How can I avoid uploading file for second test(test=Test1) ?

References:-

https://github.com/guillemhs/opensauce-selgp/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/moladek/core/saucelabs/SauceREST.java#L280

Answer (score 0):

Saucelabs changed the API, you have to use a cUrl
https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Using+Sauce+Storage+for+Test+Assets

Answer (score 0):

Sauce Labs provides temporary storage for this exact use case. You can use the following curl command to upload the file once:

```
OSX/Linux:
curl -u <sauce_username>:<sauce_access_key> -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/<sauce_username>/<upload_filename>?overwrite=true --data-binary @<path/to/your_file_name>

Windows:
curl -u <sauce_username>:<sauce_access_key> -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/<sauce_username>/<upload_filename>?overwrite=true --data-binary @/<path/to/your_file_name>
```

You can then pass the "app" desired capability and it will be available to each session being spun up by that user.

```
{"app": "sauce-storage:yourAppName.apk"}
```

More information for uploading a file here:

https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Uploading+Mobile+Applications+to+Sauce+Storage+for+Testing